# Terraform Replace - Regex Find and string Append

Tags: regex, sed, terraform

I need to use Terraform replace regex to pattern match and append.

So far I have been able to write this:

```
> replace("repo:company/example:environment:sandbox", "/(<=environment:)(.*)+(=:)/", "1_deplopy")
```

"repo:company/example:environment:sandbox"

Problem is it is appending in the wrong space

```
"repo:company/example:environment:sandbox"
```

It should be

```
"repo:company/example:environment:sandbox_deplopy"
```

Example of 3 types of variables, 2 of which will need to be altered

```
repo:company/example:environment:sandbox:job_workflow_ref:test.yaml
repo:company/example:environment:sandbox
repo:company/example:*
```

Is anyone able to help refine this to work?

Its appending at the start of the pattern, not at the end

```
replace("repo:company/example:environment:sandbox", "/(environment:*:)/", "_deplopy$1")
"repo:company/example:_deplopyenvironment:sandbox"
```

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried in Terraform so far? You don't show any Terraform attempt in your question, so it comes across as just asking people to translate code from one tool to the other, which tends to get down-votes/close-votes here as it is like asking people to do your job for you. Please show your attempts, and any errors or unexpected behavior in the question.

Comment: Apologies @MarkB, I have added where i have got with my regex

Answer (score 0):

```
> replace("repo:company/example:environment:sandbox", "/(environment:[^:]+)/", "$${1}_deplopy")
```